# htaccess Mod Rewrite ignore part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this Rewrite rule in my *htaccess* file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which rewrites `home.php?id=123` to `www.domain.com/123`

how can i make it so things like:

`www.domain.com/services/123` will still go to `home.php?id=123` but only on certain URLs

lets say i have:

```
home.php?id=1
home.php?id=2
home.php?id=3
home.php?id=4
```

and i want 1 and 3 to look like `www.domain.com/services/1` and `www.domain.com/services/2`

and then 2 and 4 just look like `www.domain.com/2` and `www.domain.com/4`

but if the user goes to `www.domain.com/services/2` or `www.domain.com/services/4` they will just get page not found?

Answer (score 0):

```
# The square brackets denote a range of allowed values
# so for /services I've specified either a 1 or a 3 is valid
RewriteRule ^services/([13])/?$ /home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# And for requests without /services I've specified that just 2 or 4
# are valid
RewriteRule ^[24]/?$  /home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# If you want all URLs that don't have /services but do have a number
# eg domain.com/3, domain.com/2345 and domain.com/95234234 then you
# can use this:
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$  /home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your original `RewriteRule` will allow `domain.com/hello` to redirect to `domain.com/home.php?id=hello`